# How to get friendly url of term sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, navigation, metadata, friendly-url

I use SharePoint 2013, Managed MetaData Service to keep terms and related Navigation Links which are referenced my publishing pages.

For Example,

```
Page url -> Term -> Friendly URL
```

- ~/Pages/Content.aspx?ctx=1  -> Contact -> ~/Summary/Contact
- ~/Pages/Content.aspx?ctx=2  -> About ->   ~/Summary/About
- ~/Pages/Content.aspx?ctx=2  -> FAQ -> ~/Summary/FAQ

This is my plan and if I navigate the page manually with friendly url everything is fine. But I need to find friendly url by its referenced term something like that.

```
 string friendlyurl = term.GetFriendlyUrl();
```

but there is not a property or etc like that to get this.

Comment: Can I assume you're using SharePoint 2013 and Managed Navigation?

Comment: Yes I am using SharePoint 2013 and Managed Navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. Just need to find term under site collection term set like below

```
SPSite site = SPSite.Current.Site;
TaxonomySession servis = new TaxonomySession(site);
siteNavigationStore = servis.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;
siteNavigationGroup = sitenavigationstore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(site);
siteNavigationSet = sitenavigationgrup.TermSets["Term Set Name"];
NavigationTerm navigatedTerm = NavigationTerm.GetAsResolvedByWeb(navigationterm, site.RootWeb, StandardNavigationProviderNames.GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider);
```

You can find friendlu URL like

```
navigatedTerm.GetWebRelativeFriendlyUrl();
```